# Symbol-only string detection

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-input, symbols, debug-symbols

I'm fairly new to Python (and programming in general), so I often end up facing really silly issues, such as the one below.

What I want is to repeatedly check if *all* the characters in a user input are symbols. When such an input is entered, I want to print that string.

Since there doesn't seem to be a way to specifically test for symbols, I decided to test for letters first, and then for numbers, and if both of them come up as negative, then it should print the text.

Here is my code:

```
while True:

  symbols = input("Enter symbol string:")

  if symbols == symbols.isalpha():
    print (symbols.isalpha())
  elif not a == a.isalpha():
    print (a.isalpha())
    break
```

Comment: What do you mean by "symbols"? Do you mean punctuation? Do you mean "anything other than letters and numbers"? Spaces? New-lines? Accented characters?

Answer (score 2):

Symbols is a little vague but here is a strategy:

```
symbols = input("Enter symbol string:")
valid_symbols = "!@#$%^&*()_-+={}[]"

has_only_symbols = True

for ch in symbols:
    if ch not in symbols:
        has_only_symbols = False
        break

if has_only_symbols:
    print('Input only had symbols')
else:
    print('Input had something other than just symbols')
```

The above code first creates a list of symbols which you want to ensure the string is created out of called `valid_symbols`.  Next it creates a variable called `has_only_symbols` that holds a value of `True` to begin with.  Next it begins to check that each character in the input string exists in `valid_symbols`.  If it hits a character which is invalid then it changes the value of `has_only_symbols` to `False` and breaks out of the for loop (no need to check the rest of the string).  After the loop is done it checks whether `has_only_symbols` is `True` or `False` and does something accordingly.

Also as a side not, some of your code is not doing what you think it is:

```
if symbols == symbols.isalpha():
    ...
```

will test if `symbols`, your input string, is equal to the result of `symbols.isalpha()` which returns a boolean `True` or `False`.   What you probably meant is just:

```
if symbols.isalpha():
    ...
```

The `elif` statement is strange as well.  You have begun referencing some variable called `a` but you do not have it defined anywhere in the code you posted. From your description and code it seems you meant to have this `elif` statement also reference `symbols` and call the `isdigit` method:

```
if symbols.isalpha():
    ...
elif symbols.isdigit():
    ...
else:
    ...
```

However this is not logically complete as a string with mixed letter, digit, and symbol will slip through.  For example `abc123!@#` will fail both the tests and get printed.  You want something more exclusive like the above code I have written.

Answer (score 0):

This is how i solved it..

```
import re

def start():
  global count
  for letter in SYMBOLS:
      if re.search(reg,SYMBOLS):
          count=count+1#just to count how many exist
          global S#if you want to store the result
          S=letter
          
      else:
          print(letter,': is not a symbol')


count = 0
SYMBOLS= input('Enter text\n')#INPUT
reg =('[@_!#$£%^&*()<>?/\|}{~:]')#SYMBOL SEARCH
start()
```

Comment: Don't you have to initialize count as 0 outside of the loop?

Answer (score 0):

Slightly updated version of Farmer Joe's code. Better processing of input included.

```
symbols = input("Enter any characters:")

valid_symbols = "!@#$%^&*()_-+={}[]"

if symbols == '':
    print("None of characters have been entered. Please try again")
else:
    for ch in symbols:
        if symbols.isalnum() is True:
            print('No symbols have been detected in the input')
            break
        else:
            if ch not in valid_symbols:
                print('There are symbols mixed with other characters')
                break
    else:
        print('Your input contains symbols only')
```